# Select all record from table except some record from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, except

I want to retrieve all the records from mem_info except the records whose username is 'qq';

following is my query

```
select * from mem_info where hashtag like '%love%' 
EXCEPT select * from mem_info where username='qq';
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * from mem_info where hashtag like '%love%' and username <>'qq';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from mem_info where username <> 'qq';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM mem_info 
WHERE hashtag LIKE '%love%' 
AND username NOT IN ('qq');
```